# SAS upload file to SFTP site

Tags: sas, sftp

I fixed one error in my code, but I still got error message 
    ERROR: Open failed for file CSVFTP
    ERROR: The connection has timed out..
    NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
    NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set.

Here is the code I am using:

```
filename csvftp ftp "text.csv"
cd = '/folder1/folder2/'
host = 'xxxx.net'
user = 'xxxxx'
pass = 'xxxxx'
rcmd = v
prompt 
debug;
proc export data = data1
outfile = csvftp
dbms = dlm
replcae;
delimiter = ',';run;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code for this operation that you're trying to automate (or whatever passes for source code with SAS).

Comment: @Kenster Source code is correct.  And - please cast a close vote next time, that's a great reason for one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the SFTP server, you have to use "filename sftp" instead of "filename ftp". This example reads a file called test.txt using the SFTP access method after connecting to the SSHD server a standard port:

```
filename myfile sftp '/users/xxxx/test.txt' host="unixhost.server.com";
data _null_;
   infile myfile truncover;
   input a $25.;
run;
```